# Java: Minecraft: Any way to cause java to "brain dump" to a fifo while it's running?

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm running a small minecraft server with this command:  /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2 -XX:+AggressiveOpts -jar minecraft_server.jar

I'm finding myself wanting to see more from the server than the author intentionally writes to the console.  So I come to you asking if you know of a way to enable some sort of debug logging and output it to a fifo.  I will then watch that fifo using swatch and trigger events that match a regular expression.

Does anyone know of a way to cause java to dump everything it's doing to a fifo during runtime?

Comment: How could you possibly get more log messages than what the programmer provides? (hint: you can't)

Comment: Do you want it to log *more* (which requires changing the program itself) or do you just want to capture the output (which you can, since it outputs it to stdout/stderr)?

Comment: What I imagine is, that while the server is running, it's processing all of the various aspects of the game.  For example, when a player moves, the server needs to know where the player moved to.  Another example; the server renders lighting differently based on time of day.  Or another example; when a player kills a monster, the server spawns new monsters in some other location.  None of these actions are intentionally logged to the regular server administration console.  (continued in next reply)

Comment: (continued from previous reply).  So I'm wondering if there's some way to ask Java to dump everything that it's doing to an output.  Similar to what one finds with a packet capture.  I'm wondering if there's some sort of way to have java "think outloud".  I found eclipse and it looks like I might be able to attach it to the minecraft server for debugging.  I'm hoping I can accomplish the same task without eclipse.  I don't need to break the code.  I just want it constantly dumping to a fifo.

Comment: @ Thanatos; I'm thinking output to stdout/stderr might be an explanation of what I'm looking for?  I'll read more about that.  Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a commenter said, you can't make an application log more than it is intended to. Although Java (the runtime itself) might have logging options (I don't know), that won't help you. If you're looking for something like "killed a monster", that is an application-level concept, not something that Java knows about. And if the application isn't logging it, and you don't have the source, then there's not much you're going to be able to do.

The only instrumentation you even could potentially do would be at the virtual machine level, but that's WAY too low level for what you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I suppose it is the "WAY too low level" that I'm trying to look at.  I understand that the concept of "killed a monster" is at the application level.  But when that happens, something must be happening under the hood.  And I'm thinking that perhaps I will be able to figure out that something unique at the very low level can be translated in to an application level event.  You've mentioned something called the virtual machine level.  I'll look in to that.  Thanks.

Comment: @Tahnka: I hate to be discouraging, but don't bother. What you're talking about is the equivalent of stepping through disassembled machine code and reverse engineering the application logic. Is it possible? Sure. But this is really really hard, incredibly time-consuming, and the kind of thing that Microsoft does for app back compatibility, and hackers do to break into secure systems. It's thankless, varsity work.